# how to update product preview image on product page like the functionality on list page , magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list

I created a configurable product, use attribute colour and size.
There is a setting on attribute colour: **"Update Product Preview Image -> yes."**

[image]

so that, on list page, when i click the colour, the product image updated.

[image]
list page [link](http://tshirt.atelier-dev.com/niveau-1.html)

But when I go to product page. I need click both colour and size, then the image can be changed. If i just select colour, the image doesn't change.

I don't want that, I want the functionality like list page.

Anyone can help me?

How can i do this functionality?